# D3 visualisation is not working on IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, d3.js

I am new to D3.js & tried to exceute [Radial Reingold–Tilford Tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) on my system using Mozila & IE9. it was working fine with mozila but not with IE9. And I also knew that IE9 onwards compatible with SVG. Any suggesstion on this front.

Comment: are you using a server or running files locally? because if it's locally that's probably the reason why you're not seeing anything on ie

Comment: I just tested it on Window 7 IE9 and it works.

Comment: I have installed jetty runner as mentioned on [offical website of D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) & successfully run the visualisation on IE9. But still facing problem when i am using Apache Tomcat for hosting these Visualisation & using IE9 for accessing them.

Comment: Working in the same way in FF and IE.

Comment: Getting error 
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
 d3.min.js, line 1 character 10922  when running D3 visualization on IE9.